# Overlay icons for applications in spread mode

Tags: unity, compiz, icons

I am looking for something like what this [gnome-shell extension offers](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/60/overlay-icons/). That is, I would like to see the icons of the applications in the spread mode. Is it, in anyway, possible in Unity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After roaming around in CCSM, I have found what I wanted.

Go to *Scale* under *Window Management* and choose either *Emblem* or *Big* for *Overlay icon*.

[image]

The emblem option gives you a small icon on the lower right hand side of the application while the Big option shows a big icon filling the entire application.